# How to only enable connect, disable drag and any other operation

Tags: mxgraph

I want to disable any other operation, but only enable connect, I don't find any options about this.
If set `graph.setEnabled(false)` I can't connect.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable cell moveable, override the `isCellMovable` method in mxGraph and return false.

```
export class Graph extends mxGraph {

  public isCellMovable() {
    return false;
  }

}
```